# compiling g++ on vmware player ubuntu - on win XP

Tags: bash, g++

I installed a virtual machine VMWare Player Ubuntu on my win XP.

At first when ever I tried to compile my program it didn't work so I installed something that allowed me to use G++
but now when i run:

```
g++ - Wall a.cpp -o out
```

It creates an executable `out`. But if I run it by the command `out`
it gives me an error

```
bash: out command not found
```

Does any one know the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is most likely compiling just fine.

Try running the program like this:

```
./out
```

It should not matter, if Ubuntu is installed in a virtual environment, at all. As I see it, the only problem is running the program :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because `.` isn't in the `PATH` by default, you need to give `bash` the *exact* name of your executable; it won't find an executable file in your current working directory. (This is a good thing; it vastly improves security on multiple-user systems, and the habit is a good one to be in on single-user systems.)

Try: `./out`.

I suggest giving the filename something *better* than `out` -- `a.out` is the typical output filename for historical reasons, but nothing says you have to keep it or anything like it. :)